# Average distance to roots of unity

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $z$ be a number in the unit disc. I would like to know a lower bound of the form

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N|z-\omega^k|\geq |z|+c$$

when $\omega$ is a primitive $N$'th root and $N>3$, where $c$ is independent of $z$ and $N$. The lower bound $|z|$ follows from the triangle inequality.

Comment: Why write $|z|$ if $z$ is on the unit circle?

Comment: Sorry, by in I meant in the disc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such bound exists for certain $c>0$, but I do not know which $c$ is optimal.

Denote $$f_n(z):=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n|z-\omega^k|,$$
then $f$ is 1-Lip as the average of 1-Lip functions.

Denote $y=z/|z|$ (or $y=1$ if $z=0$), then $|y|=1$, $|z-y|=1-|z|$ and $f_n(z)-|z|\geqslant f_n(y)-|z-y|-|z|=f_n(y)-|y|$, thus it suffices to consider $z$ with $|z|=1$. For such values of $z$ our sum is the integral sum for $\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|1-e^{it}|dt=\frac4{\pi}>1$. Therefore for any fixed $c_0\in (0,4/\pi-1)$ the inequality $f_n(z)\geqslant 1+c_0$ holds whenever $|z|=1$ and $n$ is large enough. For finitely many small values of $n$ we note that $f_n(z)>1$ for all $z$ with $|z|=1$ by triangle inequality, and by compactness there exists certain $c_1>0$ such that $f_n(z)>1+c_1$ for all $z$ with $|z|=1$ and all these $n$. Then $c=\min(c_0,c_1)$ works.

Comment: Ah the reduction to the circle itself is the trick I was missing, I had a the same Riemann sum argument in mind. I sort of hoped that there was some sort of invariance that could be exploited given the simple geometry of the problem. Anyways, nicely done!

Comment: Regarding the optimal $c$: for a fixed $n$, my calculations suggest that $f_n(z)$ is minimized at $z=1$ (and the other $n$th roots of unity).  Moreover, these optimal values $f_n(1)$ increase monotonically to their limit $4/\pi$.  Therefore, the optimal $c$ is $f_4(1)-1 = \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2} \approx 0.207107$.  It's also possible to allow $n=3$ in the original question, in which case the optimal $c$ is $f_3(1)-1 = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}-1 \approx 0.154701$.